# Is it possible to achieve partial refresh on partition materialized view by specifying particular year in oracle?

Tags: oracle, refresh, partial, partition, materialized-views

We are planning to implement partition materialized view by year and quarter.We would like to refresh the particular partition by specifying the year and quarter.

Is that possible to specify the particular year and quarter as parameter?

Comment: [Using Materialized Views with Partitioned Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/refresh.htm#GUID-7EA0FBD1-DCBD-4EBD-A131-59EE6ACC97B6)

Comment: Hi @lad2025 , I want to refresh particular partititon year and quarter by mentioning it. I can see only oracle refresh the mview based on frequency.. Any help on this